# Slicing a Picture

Tags: android

I have a

```
Picture pic = webView.capturePicture();
```

which is potentially huge and needs to be sliced into multiple chunks that will fit the screen.
The naive thing I'm currently doing is

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeigth, RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
canvas.drawPicture(pic);
fullScreenImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

What would be the efficient way to "paginate" the `Picture` to be displayed on screen (these "pages" will be later replacing one another)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just call getDrawingCache() on the webView? You won't be creating any new bitmap because it is the cache of the webview which is uses to scroll.

Comment: Thanks, Greg! That's the way I've eventually implemented it. Still, the question on slicing a Picture remains.

Comment: There is a scrolling cache though which does this for you, which is why I am wondering why you need to reimplement it.